# Duplicate entry problems while inserting into mssql db from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, duplicates

I am trying to insert pandas dataframe into mssql table but having problems because of the duplication. It is not technically duplication but it seems some destroyed characters. Below is an example: one row has clinica and the other row has  clÃ­nica but while inserting it seems converting "clÃ­nica" into clinica and throws duplication error. How can I avoid this error? Please help .

Thank you

```
clinica
clÃ­nica
```

Comment: It seems you have an unprintable character is your data too: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rtA-wIju)